# Modify PHP file after including it

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP but I think it's possible, thought unsure how to achieve this.

I've got a basic HTML markup inside a PHP file called button.php which I'm injecting into a web page using PHP include.

Here's the contents of the button.php file:

```
<div class="btn">
<div class="highlightBtn">
    <div class="btnTag">
        Submit
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The question is - how do I the value inside the  class="btnTag" tags AFTER I've included it? (I.e. after I include this file into the main page I want to be able to change it depending on where it's included, so it doesn't always have to say 'Submit').

So I imagine it might be something like

```
<? php include("button.php"); 
   //some code follows to change value inside the btnTag class  
?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You could do it before, but after would be a huge hassle, and include one of several extremely ugly and pointless solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really should be done beforehand, as in

```
// button.php
<div class="btn">
<div class="highlightBtn">
    <div class="btnTag">
        <?php echo isset($caption) ? $caption : 'Submit' ; ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

And then

```
<?php
    $caption = 'Click me'; // or comment out to get the default
    include('button.php');
?>
```

#### However, the above is not really a good approach

It would be much better to have the file just define a function when included, which you can then call whenever you need a button. For example:

```
// button.php
<?php
    function button($caption = 'Submit') {
        echo <<<END_HTML;
<div class="btn">
  <div class="highlightBtn">
    <div class="btnTag">$caption</div>
  </div>
</div>
END_HTML;
    }
```

You can then include `button.php` without any immediate effects, and whenever you want a button you can just call `button('Click me')` or just `button()`.

Comment: Thank you  that is exactly what I need. Just out of curiosity - what makes the second solution more reliable or versatile than the first?  The first solution seems to use less markup.

Comment: @user1775598: In general it's much better for your files to not do anything directly when included; it makes it easier to compose complex interactions among simpler basic parts.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it before including it:

```
$string = 'Submit';
include 'button.php';
```

and inside button.php:

```
<div class="btn">
<div class="highlightBtn">
    <div class="btnTag">
        <?php echo $string; ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

If you want to change it after the page load then you should look at [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Other solutions (for dealing with it after inclusion) would require output buffer handling, DOM handling and other painful routines that are not really an option.